# How to Read I2C Address

Tags: i2c

I ran `i2cdetect -y 1` and got the following chart back:

`0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --`

How do I interpret this address (i.e., 0x40, 0x41, etc.)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The active address is 0x65.

The row indicates the 16's place and the column indicates the one's place. So the answer is 0x60 + 0x05 = 0x65.